# Overvolting a DC motor while keeping power constant

Tags: voltage, analog, dc-motor, power-electronics, motor-controller

So I have a 36 VDC motor rated 70 A at 2000 W (mechanical output power).
I would like to run the system at 48 V (same power) because I have a lot of accessories for 48 V systems (battery chargers, DC/DC converters, motor controllers). Is it possible to overvolt the motor by 12 V (30%) if the current is decreased by 30%?

I was taught in school that the voltage rating is related to winding insulation, and I *think* 36 V insulation is capable of carrying 48 V.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: How would you decrease the current and increase voltage? This is a contradiction.

Comment: i would decrease the current using current chopper, using a higher bus voltage to achieve same power . what is the contradicition ??!!

Comment: You didn't mention about chopper. This is like: I will use higher voltage and it will be reduced by chopper, step down converter,...etc. You should seek the withstanding voltage data of your motor. Think is much higher than rated volage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 36 volt rating is most likely based on the voltage that will produce the maximum rated speed at no load (in other words, it is equal to the BEMF of the motor at top speed). The insulation breakdown voltage is typically much higher. You can run at 48 volts as long as 1) you don't exceed the maximum current, and 2) you don't exceed the maximum speed.

I regularly run 24 volt motors from a 120 or 160 volt DC bus, using a trans-impedance amplifier to control the current.

Comment: wooow , 24v volt motor from 120v bus , really impresive .. please clarify more regarding the maximum the speed ( you mean the speed the bearing can take ?? ) what is the speed limit , note the motor speed at 36v is 1800 rpm

Comment: I need to stress that I'm running the motor closed-loop when I run on a high voltage bus. A current loop with a velocity loop wrapped around it. Often, there is a position loop wrapped around the velocity loop. So I'm assured of never exceeding the max speed or current. Both the max speed and current will be among the other motor specs, assuming that you have the datasheet.

Comment: thanks , this question might be off topic , but when you design cascaded control loops , Position, Velocity and Current . do you write the model/Transfer function of the system as one equation , or do you consider each one alone and tune it separately . Implementing such systems is not very documented over the internet only theories and general ideas are presented the last time i searched.

Comment: In the system I was referencing above, each loop was designed separately, and runs independently. The current loop is a standard analog motor amplifier. There are multiple velocity loops (analog, digital and hybrid), two different position loops and three feedback modes. Each may or may not be enabled (except for the current loop, which is always enabled). Because of the many combinations, I can't really model it, outside of Bode-plots for individual components. I never know in advance what the load will be, so there is an built-in tuning routine. There are 30 parameters for tuning.

Comment: OMG 30 parameter for tuning and " tuning routine" ( probably an auto tuner or on the fly changer controller by fuzzy logic ?!) .... and i thought 2x kp and 2x kpi are hard to tune .. that is just amazing , i wonder how this works by trail and error since no model is available, there is just too many variables (30) to tune .

Comment: It's not hard to tune at all. Most of those parameters are motor / encoder / tachometer specifications, like the tacho voltage constant or encoder resolution, or your desired performance, like maximum velocity, maximum acceleration and maximum jerk. Some parameters are for safety, like maximum allowable following error, maximum velocity error and two maximum temperatures (for both motor and amp). The loops were also designed to be tuned non-iteratively, in that if you tune each parameter in the correct order, you never need to backup to re-tune a previous one.

Answer (score 2):

The since the speed is directly proportional to voltage, the motor will attempt to run at 133% of rated speed. If you are driving something like a fan for centrifugal pump, the torque load on the motor would increase to 1.33 X 1.33 = 1.77 pr 177% of rated load. The increased load will prevent the motor from going that fast, but it is still likely to be overloaded and overheat rather quickly. The driven equipment might not fare too well either. Look for or design a speed controller that will limit he voltage to 36 volts.

It is also possible that the commutator will have arcing among the segments with increased voltage. The winding insulation will probably not have a problem.

Re comment

With traction applications, the load torque will increase with speed to the extent that the vehicle is subject to aerodynamic drag. Increasing the voltage does not increase the torque capability of the motor. Therefore, any load that requires more torque to operate at a higher speed has the potential of overload the motor if it is operated above rated speed. With a traction application, I would think that you would need a speed controller. I see that you are intending to use a chopper. That should be configured to adjust and limit the speed and limit the current. Since it controls the voltage by controlling the duty cycle, but the peak voltage would still be 48 V. There may be no problem with the commutator, but you should look to see if there is any problem.

Comment: the load is not a fan or a pump , it is a traction application , so the extra torque is welcomed , as long as the motor tempreture stays within limits . commutator arcing seems scary , i donot know the voltage is was designed for , but looking inside it looks similar to any commutator of a 72v or higher motor